Which analysis instead of linear regression?
I have collected data pertaining to suffering (scale from 0 to 8, higher is worse) and cognitive distortion (0 to 40, higher is worse) for a study with ~ 200 participants. My hypothesis is that there is an association.
The scores are correlated (r = 0.71) and I was planning a simple linear regression analysis, but despite weighted least squares, sqrt() and log() transformations the residuals in the linear model remain non-normally distributed. Both variables are non-normal, with the mode response 0.
What sort of analysis might be reasonable to apply here?

(1) What do you expect to learn from the regression that you don't already know from the correlation? (2) Model assumptions in statistics are generally not precisely fulfilled, and in many situations (but not all) analyses can be fine that "assume" normality even if data are non-normal. We'd need to see the data to say anything about this here.  (3) Pearson correlation can be problematic under certain deviations from normality as well, and you may want to run a Spearman correlation.

If you do need to learn more than Spearman’s rank correlation you can take a look at semiparametric ordinal regression, see e.g. here.  Ordinal regression is invariant to how Y is transformed (same result for Y as for log(Y) etc.).

Summarizing comments:
If there no other variables to be modeled, then the Spearman rank correlaion is a good choice. It makes no assumptions about distributions, as it works solely with the ranks on the two scales.
If you need to include other variables in the model (e.g., age, sex) then you can use ordinal regression, as Frank Harrell recommends.
